# Java remove millisecond precision from long value

Tags: java

so from this :

```
1459245759880
```

to this

```
1459245759000
```

Comment: Did you try anything, like divide by 1000 and then multiply by 1000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usual integer rounding?

```
long millis = 1459245759880L;
long rounded = millis / 1000 * 1000;
```

Using Java time (convenient if you need to do date/time operations on the result - in that case you can work with the instant):

```
Instant i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
long rounded = i.toEpochMilli();
```

More convoluted (and probably not very clear):

```
long rounded = 1000 * TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
//OR
long rounded = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: What is timeUnit here ? from which class it comes ? is it part of jdk

Comment: @Panther yes, since Java 5... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: Thanks I was not aware

Comment: Should the `TimeUnit` based version be `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), TimeUnit.SECONDS)` ?

Comment: @msandiford It could indeed thanks. I personally find the method badly named because I never know what is converted to what without reading the docs.

Answer (score 3):

```
 long x = 1459245759880;
 long y = x - (x % 1000);
```

Use simply the modulo operator to get reminder and then subtract it from the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this

```
long value = 1459245759880L;
System.out.println(1000 * (value / 1000));
```